# Java EE 7: Login using events

Tags: java, jsf

In my application, users can log in as users or admins.

Is it possible to implement this using events in Java EE 7?

Right now, my code looks like this:
a) ManagedBean for JSF-View

```
public String validateUsernamePassword() {
        Admin admin = new Admin();
        admin.setPassword(pwd);
        admin.setUserName(userName);
        adminLoginEvent.fire(admin);
        return Pages.CONSOLE;

    }
```

b) Service that listens for the event:

```
public void onAdminLogin(@Observes final Admin admin) {

        List<Admin> foundAdmin = adminLoginDao.login(admin);

        if (foundAdmin != null) {                 
            HttpSession session = sessionController.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("username", foundAdmin.get(0).getUserName());
            consoleController.setAdmin(foundAdmin.get(0));
        }
    }
```

The problem, of course is, that in the managed bean I cant tell whether login was successful. I could fire another event in the `onAdminLogin` method but where should I listen for that?

Do I *have* to do this by having `onAdminLogin` return a boolean value which I then use in the `validateUsernamePassword` method?

Comment: Nothing is clear as to why you need to fire a CDI event which has to be listened to by a service. This is a big design flaw, if this is really **a real service** where you are exposing `HttpSession` from the Servlet API.

Comment: I am guessing that this sessionController.getSession() obtains a reference to the session through the JSF FacesContext class?

Comment: @Tiny: Well, this service class is simply another layer between my managed bean and my DAO. Isnt that the usual architecture?

Comment: @Gimby: Yes, thats the case.

Comment: I don't get the statement "The problem, of course is, that in the managed bean I cant tell whether login was successful." then - yes you can; the session has an attribute "username" set after a successful login. You might turn that into a slightly cleaner solution with a proper bean rather than only a String, but yes you can know.

Comment: @Gimby what exactly to you mean by a proper bean? My SessionController is a SessionScoped bean.

Comment: @user3629892 set a bean with login properties rather than only a username as a String is what I mean. But that is not the relevant part; I still don't understand why you think you can't know the login was successful. There must be more to your question than you are currently asking.